# Date comparison error using >= operator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

Hi I'm trying to compare dates from objects that are relevant to today or the future. If it's from yesterday and before, it shouldn't show up. That's the conditions.

When I compare today's date to `new Date()`, that condition should be true but it's returning false so as a result the conditions aren't working as they should. What's wrong with this code?

```
data = [
   '0': {type: "recare", value: "Hello", date: "2018-06-05", ... },
   '1': {type: "tocall", value: "World", date: "2018-06-13", ... },
   '2': {type: "recare", value: "People", ...}
];

console.log(new Date(data[0].date) >= new Date())
//returns: false

    console.log(new Date(data[1].date) >= new Date())
//returns: true
```

Why does it return false? for the the 2nd object, it returns true as 06-13 is in the future compared to today (06-05)

Comment: Because `"2018-06-05"` corresponds to the absolute first time in this day, and your code is running now. So the time now is greater than the time it was just after midnight last night.

Comment: The dates in your object don't record a time of day, so they default to `00:00`, which is midnight last night.

Comment: @Pointy - “*... and is parsed as UTC*.” ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the new Date() includes the current time component as well. You can fix it by using new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0).

```js
data = [
   {type: "recare", value: "Hello", date: "2018-06-06" },
   {type: "tocall", value: "World", date: "2018-06-13" },
   {type: "recare", value: "People"}
];

console.log(new Date(data[0].date) >= new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))
//returns: false

    console.log(new Date(data[1].date) >= new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))
//returns: true
```

Comment: “2018-06-06” will be treated as UTC, whereas *setHours* sets the local time, which may produce unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

if you try to log the first two values you'll see different output

```js
const data = [
    { type: 'recare', value: 'Hello', date: '2018-06-05' },
    { type: 'tocall', value: 'World', date: '2018-06-13' },
    { type: 'recare', value: 'People' },
];
// this will evaulate to the date since the day started 00:00
console.log(new Date(data[0].date));
// this will evaulate to the current time 
console.log(new Date()) ; 
 // so new Date() is >= than new Date(data[0].data) ; 
// so this will be false 
console.log(new Date(data[0].date) >= new Date());
```

you can compare the 2 dates with other props like **getHours** and **getMonth** for example , there are many other props you can use

learn more about the Date Object 
[Date Javascript MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 0):

**@Sam**, try the below code.

```
var data = [
   {type: "recare", value: "Hello", date: "2018-06-05" },
   {type: "tocall", value: "World", date: "2018-06-13" },
   {type: "recare", value: "People", date: "2018-06-06"}
]

var date = new Date()
console.log(date)
var year = date.getFullYear() 
var month = date.getMonth() 
var day = date.getDate()

console.log(year, month, day)

var today = new Date(year, month, day)
console.log(new Date(data[0].date) >= today) // returns false

console.log(new Date(data[0].date) == today); //returns: true

console.log(new Date(data[1].date) > today); //returns: true
```

Output:

```
Tue Jun 05 2018 22:41:27 GMT+0200 (CEST)
2018 5 5
true
false
true
```

> Please have a focus on the following 2 lines of codes as the above provided solution is based on this.

✓ The following 2 statements are equivalent to each other

```
console.log(new Date("2018-08-07"));
console.log(new Date(2018, 7, 7)); // month ranges from 0-11 in call to Date() contructor
```

Output:

```
Tue Aug 07 2018 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Tue Aug 07 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```